# Como voltar cena com botão do celular

Tags: react-native

A única forma que meu app tem pra voltar de cena é pelo botão que eu criei, quando eu clico no botão voltar do meu celular o aplicativo fecha.

Código do botão que criei:

```
<TouchableHighlight
    underlayColor={'#66CDAA'}
    onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigator.pop();
    }}>
        <Image  source={require('../imgs/Voltar.png')}
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Para navegar entre as cenas utilizei o `import {Navigator} from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';` e após importar as cenas que navegarei utilizei este código:

```
 <Navigator
          initialRoute={{id: 'CenaInicial'}}
          renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
            if(route.id === 'CenaInicial')
            {
              return(<CenaInicial navigator={navigator} />);
            }
```

Assim eu declarei todas as cenas e em cada uma delas eu coloquei o comando `this.props.navigator.push({ id: 'NomeDaCena' });` para alterar a cena. O problema é que só esse comando não esta sendo suficiente para voltar a cena com o botão do celular.

O que tenho que fazer para o botão de voltar do celular fazer com que mostre a cena anterior ao invés de fechar o aplicativo?

Comment: Podes colocar o código completo? De onde vem `styles` por exemplo? O que é `this.props.navigator`?

Comment: atualizei a pergunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posso estar enganado mas acredito que o Navigator já faz isso automaticamente. Ao clicar no botão de voltar do celular ele mostra a cena anterior `navigator.pop()`

O que pode estar acontecendo é que sua pilha de navegação está vazia. Assim, realmente o aplicativo irá fechar.

Talvez o problema se encontre no método que você está usando para avançar uma cena.

Eu utilizo da seguinte forma:

```
import { createRouter } from '@exponent/ex-navigation';

import Cena from './screens/Cena';

const Router = createRouter(() => ({
    NomeDaCena: () => Cena})
)

navigator.push(Router.getRoute("NomeDaCena",{prop: 'Valor'}))
```

Caso você continue verificando que o erro não é no avanço da cena, pode tentar adicionar Listeners ao botão fisico do android:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html

Para isso basta fazer, nas telas em que deseja voltar a cena caso o botão seja apertado:

```
  import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

      {...}

      componentWillMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress',() => {
         this.props.navigator.pop();
        });
      }
```

Edit:
Caso usar o BackHandler não se esqueça de remover o Listener quando o componente for desmontado para evitar multiplas chamadas de `navigator.pop()`:

```
 componentWillUnmount() {
   BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress',() => {
     this.props.navigator.pop();
   });
 }
```

Comment: O BackHandler é usado no index.android ou nas cenas que terão a opção de voltar?

Comment: Nesse código exemplificado deve ser usado nas cenas, visto que os componentes devem ter a prop navigator.

Comment: Desculpa perguntar mas é que comecei a aprender react-native a pouco tempo. Em algumas das cenas eu utilizo vários 'this.props.navigator.push', eu devo usar o código do BackHandler apenas uma vez em cada cena logo após o 'render(){' ou dentro de cada TouchableHighlight que altera a cena?

Comment: Esse código está definindo um Listener.
Um listener é uma estrutura programada que ouve eventos os quais, foram registrados para ele. Isso significa, que uma vez declarado, sempre que o evento "hardwareBackPress" for chamado, o código do _handler_ será executado.

Você só precisa definir esse listener uma unica vez em todo o seu código (index.android), caso o seu _handler_ sempre seja o mesmo.
Ou nos metodos de **componentWillMount()** e **componentWillUnmount()** de cada cena, como foi exemplificado na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Olá !

Já conseguiu resolver este problema ?
Caso esteja usando o react-navigation

Podes adicionar ao construtor de seu componente de navegação o seguinte trecho:

```
    import { Platform, BackHandler } from 'react-native';


export class AppWithNavigationState extends Component {

      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
      }

      shouldCloseApp(nav) {
         return nav.index == 0;
      }

      // Esta função valida o SO do usuário, caso o desenvolvimento seja para ambas as plataformas.

      isAndroidApp() {
        return Platform.OS == 'android';
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        // backPress é o evento de Back() executado pelo Hardware.
        BackHandler.addEventListener('backPress', () => {
          if (this.shouldCloseApp(this.props.nav) || !this.isAndroidApp()) return false

          // Caso esteja usando o react-navigation ele vai disparar um evento de navegação (ele integra com o redux)
          this.props.dispatch({
            type: 'Navigation/BACK'
          })

          // ou logo abaixo algum código pra remover sua cena da pilha.
          ... 
              return true
            })
          }
```

Deve ser lembrado que esta solução somente se aplica para Android.

Espero ajudar.

Comment: Infelizmente ainda não achei a resposta para meu problema.
Testei sua resposta e ao rodar deu um erro: "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'nav.index')", por acaso você saberia como resolver?

Comment: Quando retirei o 

`shouldCloseApp(nav) {
         return nav.index == 0;
      }`

deu outro erro: "undefined is not a function (evaluating '_this2.shouldCloseApp(_this2.props.nav)')"

Comment: @MurilloCarvalho Então a função shouldCloseApp, é uma validação pra checar a pilha da Navegação. Isso porque no meu código eu estou usando o React-Navigation com Stack Navigator. No seu caso, podes substituir a condição pelo trecho a seguir: `if (route.id === 'CenaInicial' || !this.isAndroidApp())`

Comment: Tentei substituir mas deu outro erro, deu "unespected token" e o problema foi no "." (ponto) do "route.id".

Comment: C. Silveira, você saberia resolver o problema do "unespected token"? Ainda nao consegui resolver o problema e não estou achando nenhuma saída

Comment: Ou @MurilloCarvalho , talvez eu consiga te ajudar sim. Voce pode postar uma imagem com o erro ou algo do tipo ? Quer me passar seu repo pra eu baixar o código e tentar te ajudar ?